# Display category name and title of last post (in custom post type)

Tags: custom-post-types

All is in the title of the question.
Title here show the name of the page, i want to show the name of the last post, but i don't know how to do it !

Thanks

```
<div class="grid-item">
    <?php $terms = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'category','exclude'=>array(1)) );?>
    <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->term_id); ?>" title="<?php echo $term->name; ?>">
            <div class="item">
                <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume you're meaning that you want to get the title of the last term in the `get_terms()` query in your code? Or are you looking to get the latest post in the current term in the `foreach` loop? Not sure what you mean by "last post".

Comment: Agree - your question is vague (especially when looking at your code).  You have asked to get the title/category of the last post, but you are iterating through terms within a post.  If you want the last post, you'll first need to pull that in (wp_query object maybe).  Then, it will be simple to get the title/category of it.

Comment: With this code, i can show the name of the categories of my website. And i want behind this, show the title of the last post of each category ! I don't know if it's more clear ? Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to WordPress Development SE. I do not doubt that the way you asked the question feels complete and detailed to you. However, you are the only one familiar with your project while the rest of us are going to need details and clarity. Please edit your question to provide this. Your comment, for example, adds new information that would help your question so I know there is more you could add with your edit.